# How to send request body of post request in HttpClient destination?

Tags: http, streamsets

I am using stremasets ETL tool to transform data. After transformation sending data to a rest service with HTTPClient Destination as POST request. 
but there I did't find any place to send request body. So how can I trigger rest with post data??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The body of the request is the record that is passed to the HTTP Client destination. You just need to set the Data Format to whatever the REST service is expecting.